# What is "function()->" called?

Tags: c++

This may be a very noobish question but what exactly is this called? I've seen 
`function()->` 
many times and never found out what it is called. Also how can I create my own?

```
GetDocument()->SetModifiedFlag(1);
```

Comment: Where did you see that? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What are you asking exacty? `function()->` is just a call to a function `function` that (obviously) returns a pointer that you then dereference. What is it about that you want to know or are unclear about?

Comment: It is equivalent to `(*GetDocument()).SetModifiedFlag(1);`... See more about [member-access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)...

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly it is a pointer to a member function's return value. How would you set this up in the .h file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If used for a function definition, it is called a [return type declaration](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2017/01/17/pros-and-cons-of-alternative-function-syntax-in-cpp/).

```
auto myfunctiona() -> int 
{
    return 0; 
}
```

If it is used in an expression, it is the [arrow operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_member_operators.htm) which dereferences a pointer to access a member. In your example, the function `GetDocument()` needs to return a pointer to an object. The type of that object must have a member function `SetModifiedFlag()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the hint:  I didn't see the the edit of the question, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 8):

This contsruction has no name, because there is nothing special about it.

It's just operator `->` applied to a value returned by `function()`.

Comment: In the example, it takes the return value of the `SetModifiedFlag(1)`and does what?

Comment: @Abdu • Without the code for `GetDocument` and whatever it returns ... probably a `Document*`, and the code for that which would include a `SetModifiedFlag` member function... well, we'd just be speculating.  I speculate SetModifiedFlag will set the flag to 1 that is contained in the Document instance.

Comment: @Abdu Unless whatever `GetDocument` returns has its' `operator->` overloaded, then the code is equivalent to `something *ptr = GetDocument(); ptr->SetModifiedFlag(1)`.